# Using a mailto link, how do I prevent Gmail from stripping the = sign and everything after it from the URL's query string?

Tags: php, encoding, query-string, mailto

I am trying to format a mailto link that works with a variety of mail clients. This works with Mac's "Mail" and Thunderbird. However, when I click the link on my Android phone, the query string in the URL is stripped starting with the equals sign. I have tried to add code to specify the content type, to parse the query string and re-add it, etc. So far, nothing works. Here's my code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
    $BASEURL = strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?');
    echo '
    <li><a href="mailto:?subject=An Article Worth Reading: ' . $ALTITLE . '&amp;body=I found this article worthwhile and think you will too:%0D%0A %0D%0A
    https://worldviewpublications.org' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTPS_HOST']) . $BASEURL . "?" . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) . "%0D%0A";
    echo '">share with a friend</a></li>
    ';
?>
```

I'm pretty proficient in html/css but a beginner with PHP, so I am not at all sure about the efficacy of some of the PHP I added. I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Apply proper URL encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the solution to the problem, which I'm posting below. I've removed the code shared in my initial post that didn't help (in case you're wondering, the nonbreaking space after the colon is for Thunderbird, which does not honor the new line code).

The solution was to encode the = sign. In order to do that, I first extracted the first and last parts of the URL: (1) the first part without the query string and (2) the query string after the = sign. Then I concatenated it back together, spelling out the middle part between the main URL and the unique code at the end of the query string — the question mark (encoded as %3f), the query code identifier (IDN), and the equal sign (encoded %3d). This solution passes the entire URL, including all of the query string, to my gmail client when I'm using my Android phone.

```
<?php
    $BASEURL = strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?');
    $IDEN = ltrim(($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']), 'IDN=');
    echo '
    <li><a href="mailto:?subject=An Article Worth Reading: ' . $ALTITLE . '&amp;body=%0D%0AI found this article worthwhile and think you will too:&nbsp;

    %0D%0A%0D%0A' . htmlspecialchars("\n\r") . 'https://worldviewpublications.org' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTPS_HOST']) . $BASEURL . '%3fIDN%3d' . $IDEN;
    echo '">share with a friend</a></li>
    ';
?>
```